# How to insert optional character UNIX variables?

Tags: unix, yaml

In configuration file in an URL I'm trying refer to environment variable. This variable is optional. If that variable is set I need to insert after it a dot if not then ignore the dot.

```
https://${WORKSPACE}.web.com
```

What is the neat way to have that dot after variable only when workspace is specified? I was thinking about construction with question mark '?' but have no idea how apply to my solution.
example:

```
https://workspace.web.com  - environment specified
https://web.com - environment not specified
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are writing a shell script using bash for example. In that case, I would do something like this:

```
[ "${WORKSPACE}" == "" ] && MYURL="https://web.com" || MYURL="https://${WORKSPACE}.web.com"; echo "MYURL=${MYURL}"
```

Comment: Actually it's not shell script, it's spring configuration file .yml, I've just edited and added new tag, and I think I'm looking for something neater and brief.